# setbeamerfont {alerted text} in article mode

Tags: beamer, fonts, beamerarticle

I can't change the alerted text font in `article` mode without changing the `beamerbasearticle.sty` file. With the following MWE, the alerted text it still `\itshape` and not `\bfseries`. It's working in `presentation` mode though.

```
\documentclass[article]{extarticle}
\RequirePackage{beamerarticle}

\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{series=\bfseries,shape=\upshape}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \normal text
 \alert{alerted text}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beamerarticle` uses the *templates* `alerted text begin` and `alerted text end` to set the alerted text in italics; for the record, the original definitions in `beamerbasearticle.sty`:

```
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{alerted text begin}{default}{\ifmmode\else\begin{itshape}\fi}
\defbeamertemplate<article>*{alerted text end}{default}{\ifmmode\else\end{itshape}\fi}
```

so you need to set (or define) those templates appropriately; for example:

```
\documentclass[article]{extarticle}
\RequirePackage{beamerarticle}

\mode<article>{%
\setbeamertemplate{alerted text begin}{\bfseries\upshape}
\setbeamertemplate{alerted text end}{}
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 regular text \alert{alerted text} regular text
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had tried \defbeamertemplate but not \setbeamertemplate...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, beamer explicitly makes `\setbeamerfont` a no-operation in article mode, unfortunately inlcuding not only the command itself, but pretty much the entire subsystem, down to the keys that aren't defined in article mode. (So there's no two-line fix for this.)